# refCnt: 0 exception in Micronaut with reactive streams - Microservice

Tags: java, spring, netty, rx-java2, micronaut

I am currently having three Microservices.

**A** is a Producer, **B** an intermediate consumer that decrypts the data stream from A and **C** the final consumer that uses the decrypted data.

This is done with Reactive Streams (JavaRX2) and Micronaut 3

The code failing in **B** looks like this:

```
@Produces(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Get("/{datasetId}/entries/{entryId}")
@ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.IO)
@Blocking
public Single<Flowable<byte[]>> getEntry(
        @NotBlank @PathVariable final String datasetId
) {
    final PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
    final PipedInputStream pipedInputStream = this.getPipedInputStream(pos);

    final Future<OutputStream> futureOutputStream = this.storageExecutor.submit(() ->
        this.getCipherOutputStream(datasetId, pos));

    final Future<Flowable<byte[]>> futureFlowable = this.storageExecutor.submit(
            () -> this.storageClient.getEntry(datasetId, this.authentication.getAccessToken(this.sidecarConfiguration.getStorage().getAudienceId()))
                    .observeOn(this.storageScheduler)
                    .map(b -> {
                        final OutputStream cipherOutputStream = futureOutputStream.get();
                        log.trace("Writing {} bytes into piped stream.", b.length);
                        cipherOutputStream.write(b);
                        return pipedInputStream.readNBytes(pipedInputStream.available());
                    })
                    .doOnError(e -> log.error("Error processing outputstream:", e))
                    .doFinally(() -> {
                        pos.close();
                    }));
    return Single.fromFuture(futureFlowable, Schedulers.from(this.storageExecutor));
}

private OutputStream getCipherOutputStream(final String datasetId, final OutputStream rawOutputStream) throws DatasetManagementException {
    try {
        final Dataset dataset = this.doGetDataset(datasetId).orElseThrow(() -> new DatasetManagementException("Cannot find dataset."));

        final Dataset.Entry entry = dataset.getEntries().stream()
            .findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new DatasetManagementException("Cannot find dataset entry."));

        // get encrypted keys from escrow
        final Set<EncryptedKey> eKeySet = this.keyEscrowService.getKey(datasetId, this.sidecarConfiguration.getTenant());

        final KeyPair keyPair = this.getKeyPair(eKeySet);
        // decrypt dataset key
        final SymmetricKey symmetricKey = this.keyEncrypter.decrypt(keyPair.encryptedSymmetricKey, keyPair.privateKey);

        log.trace("decrypt stream opened.");
        // wrap in decrypting stream and return that to the caller
        return this.streamEncrypter.decryptStream(symmetricKey.getBytes(), entry.getIv(), rawOutputStream);
    } catch (final CryptoException | KeyEscrowException ex) {
        throw new DatasetManagementException("Cannot create decryption stream.");
    }
}
```

How I provide the used Beans (actually maybe more important what I provide :))

```
@Factory
public class SidecarBeans {

    /**
     * Executor service for working with storage.
     *
     * @param config sidecar configuration
     * @return service instance
     */
    @Bean
    @Named("storageExecutor")
    public ExecutorService storageExecutor(SidecarConfiguration config) {
        return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(config.getStorageWorkers());
    }

    /**
     * Scheduler for working with storage.
     *
     * @param storageExecutor storage executor
     * @return service instance
     */
    @Bean
    @Named("storageScheduler")
    public Scheduler storageScheduler(@Named("storageExecutor") ExecutorService storageExecutor) {
        return Schedulers.from(storageExecutor);
    }
}
```

**When running the rest I receive**

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0
```

**Full Stacktrace below my last sentence**

I have found some references for **Spring** that lead to an Issue with netty, assuming the `max-in-memory-size` is wrong and for some that was the solution. Unfortunately Micronaut does not offer the same way to solve this.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0

    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.FutureSingleObserver.get(FutureSingleObserver.java:86)
    at DatasetV1ControllerGetEntryMockedTest.getEntry(DatasetV1ControllerGetEntryMockedTest.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestMethod(InvocationInterceptor.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.ensureAccessible(AbstractByteBuf.java:1454)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkIndex(AbstractByteBuf.java:1383)
    at io.netty.buffer.UnsafeByteBufUtil.getBytes(UnsafeByteBufUtil.java:481)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.getBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:130)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledSlicedByteBuf.getBytes(PooledSlicedByteBuf.java:235)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.getBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:490)
    at io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil.getBytes(ByteBufUtil.java:1328)
    at io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil.getBytes(ByteBufUtil.java:1301)
    at io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil.getBytes(ByteBufUtil.java:1293)
    at io.micronaut.buffer.netty.NettyByteBuffer.toByteArray(NettyByteBuffer.java:228)
    at io.micronaut.core.convert.DefaultConversionService.lambda$registerDefaultConverters$69(DefaultConversionService.java:909)
    at io.micronaut.core.convert.DefaultConversionService.convert(DefaultConversionService.java:140)
    at io.micronaut.core.convert.ConversionService.convert(ConversionService.java:93)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.interceptor.HttpClientIntroductionAdvice.lambda$httpClientResponseStreamingPublisher$6(HttpClientIntroductionAdvice.java:469)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.Publishers$1.doOnNext(Publishers.java:214)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onNext(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.onNext(StrictSubscriber.java:89)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onNext(ReactorSubscriber.java:57)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.MicronautFlux$AfterNextOperator$1.onNext(MicronautFlux.java:92)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onNext(ReactorSubscriber.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:712)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(FluxFlatMap.java:347)
    at reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.request(StrictSubscriber.java:138)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscriptions.SubscriptionHelper.deferredRequest(SubscriptionHelper.java:219)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.StrictSubscriber.request(StrictSubscriber.java:70)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.request(StrictSubscriber.java:138)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.runAsync(FlowableObserveOn.java:414)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableObserveOn$BaseObserveOnSubscriber.run(FlowableObserveOn.java:176)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: This is could be an issue in your `DatasetV1ControllerGetEntryMockedTest` maybe you are trying to mock (indirectly) a netty buffer? Could you post the code of your test.

Comment: That issue appears in all other environments too unfortunatly. It is not the test.

Comment: A few hints, your exception is raised here: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/3.1.x/core/src/main/java/io/micronaut/core/convert/DefaultConversionService.java#L908 This happens when an already released `io.micronaut.core.io.buffer.ByteBuffer` is released. The  root cause is an upstream call to another http service. Check if you drain, release, close an `ByteBuffer` or facade somewhere in your codebase.. to validate this theory remove the upstream call.

Comment: I don't have any implicit access to that in my code. What upstream call should I remove? The only upstream call I have to the producer is visible in code `storageClient.getEntry`

Comment: Then you should remove the call to `storageClient.getEntry` and see if it works, as they issue imho is located there. In addition you could add `Hooks.onOperatorDebug();` to gain more debug details, you could also remove the superfluous `@ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.IO)` and  `@Blocking` as your controller method is non-blocking. If this does not help enable netty debug logging and find out who is  reducing the reference counter for the netty buffer.